# WebDriver - Switch to new Window and selecting dropdown is not working in IE

Tags: selenium, webdriver, dropdown

Trying to switch to new window tab and then selecting a item from dropdown list is not working..

```
public static void handleNewTabWindow() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@src='/images/buttons/gl_upload.gif']")).click();
    String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();
    for (String Child_Window : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
        driver.switchTo().window(Child_Window);
        WebElement dropdown = getWhenVisible(By.xpath(".//select[@name='UPLOAD_ORG_ID']"));
        dropdown.click();
        getWhenVisible(By.xpath(".//option[contains(text(), 'CI Borrower')]")).click();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(Parent_Window);
    driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must wait until a new window will appear on the screen before switching to it. Your code is trying to switch immediately after clicking on the button, in a couple of miliseconds - the browser is not so quick, you must wait a couple of seconds or so.
A not very elegant, but a quick solution is to introduce a fixed `Thread.sleep( 2000 );` here:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@src='/images/buttons/gl_upload.gif']")).click();
Thread.sleep( 2000 );
String Parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

but this doesn't work very well.

---

A better solution is to implement a method that will wait until a new window appears on the screen (but no longer than some fixed timeout - for example 30-60 seconds). For example one of the most used method in our project is a method that waits for a window with a given title, something like this (code skeleton):

```
void waitForWindowWithTitleAndSwitchToIt( String windowTitle, int timeoutInSeconds ){
   .... 
   while( timeout-not-expired ){
      handles = driver.getWindowHandles():
      for( String handle: handles ){
         driver.switchTo.window( handle );
         if( driver.getTitle().contains( windowTitle ) ){
             // found a window with a given title
             return;
         }
      }
      sleep( for a 1-2 seconds ); 
      // and try again 
   }
   throw new TimeoutException(
          String.format("A browser window named %s doesn't appear on the screen", windowTitle )
          );
   }
```

We have implemented a couple of such methods in our project, which wait for a new window using different criteria: wait for window with a given exact title, for a window which a title that contains a given substring, for a window with a given string in the page source, for a window with a given (sub)string in the url, etc. etc.